# Filter events in full Calendar using checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, calendar, fullcalendar, filtering

I'm filtering my events, using checkboxes and rerender when checking a checkbox.

Problem I'm having is that after implementing this working code I not able to select a period of time in my calendar (dragging a time slot isn't possible anymore)

This is the code I use.
HTML checkboxes:

```
<div class="instructor_selector">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="instructorId" value="AA" checked>AA<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="instructorId" value="BB" checked>BB<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="instructorId" value="JJ" checked>JJ<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
        $('.instructor_selector').on('change',function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        });
</script>
```

Full Calendar:

```
    eventRender:  function(event, element) {
        var returnvalue = false;
        $("input[name=instructorId]:checked").each(function() {
            var result = this.value == event.instructorId;
            returnvalue = returnvalue || result;
            });
        return returnvalue;         
    },
```

Full Calender does a "eventRender" when moving the mouse over the calendar.
I think I need some extra condition in the full calender code. So my "filter"-code only runs when clicking on a checkbox.
Problem with this code is that i can't click-drag-select a period in the fullcalendar.

Just to make thing more clear:
JSBIN:

Possible to drag and select time period:
http://jsbin.com/poboka/4/edit?html,js,output

Not possible to drag and select time periode (with working filter code, checkboxes on top of page)
http://jsbin.com/poboka/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I see you asked a lot of question without marking one as right. Please mark the right answer in your questions. I would help other users and its how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your JavaScript code should look like this:

```
<script>
    $(input[name=instructorId]).on('change',function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    });
</script>
```

This would trigger your rerendering when one of the checkboxes are selected or deselected.

Comment: My filter and script is working as it is. Only problem is that my code in "eventRender:  function(event, element)" is preventing me to drag and select a period on my calendar by mouse.

Comment: `So my "filter"-code only runs when clicking on a checkbox.` wasn't that your question?

Comment: Your code isn't working well for me. My "script" code works. The filtering part is working perfect and events are rendered when clicking on a checkbox. Problem is that I cant use the drag-select period functionality when I my code in the fullcalendar part.

Comment: okay, I was assuming that the on change event on the parent Div `.instructor_selector` was interfering with your other code